# Mobile menu icon not toggling classes

Tags: javascript, html

Have a simple JS question most likely. Have this code but want to move the click event out of the HTML

HTML

```
   <button id="mobile-icon" class="lg:hidden mb-4">
     <i onclick="changeIcon(this)" class="fa-solid fa-bars text-xl"></i>
   </button>
```

Here's my JS but it doesn't seem to work after I remove the click event from the HTML onclick="changeIcon(this)" and try to do it in the JS. Thanks

```
const mobile_icon = document.getElementById('mobile-icon');
const mobile_menu = document.getElementById('mobile-menu');
const hamburger_icon = document.querySelector("#mobile-icon i");

function openCloseMenu() {
    mobile_menu.classList.toggle('block');
    mobile_menu.classList.toggle('active');
  }

  function changeIcon(icon) {
    icon.classList.toggle("fa-xmark");
  }

  mobile_icon.addEventListener('click', openCloseMenu);
  hamburger_icon.addEventListener('click', changeIcon(icon));
```

Comment: Actually figured it out. Thanks